# Ready transaction queue never empties after heavy load

Tags: transaction-pool, mempool, tx-pool

After a heavy load test with thousands of transactions from a fixed set of accounts (maybe relevant due to [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/high-transaction-throughput-single-acccount/2341)), the ready pool of some nodes never empties, and for this reason many transactions get lost.

It's a Frontier based PoA chain currently with 1 validator for Aura/Grandpa and the others are full nodes.

- Block slot: 1s
- BlockWeights: ~500ms
- BlockGasLimit: 10M
  [image]

The test sends thousands of ERC-20 transfers via WebSocket and listens to their events in one of the nodes

In the logs of one of the nodes I can see that the ready queue ahs the 2812 txs:

```
2023-09-27 17:53:35.070 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: Resubmitted. Took 132 ms. Status: PoolStatus { ready: 2812, ready_bytes: 940124, future: 818, future_bytes: 295298 }
```

The only way to clear the queue seems to be restarting the nodes.

edit: more info about the chain